# How to host .NET website on amazon web service?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to host a .NET website on amazon web service. I did a bit research on google and found that AWS EC2 provides such facility but i cannot understand what it is and what other components(services) i would be needing. I found a link on AWS website which gave me an estimated monthly expense of hosting. but problem is that they quoted various services in that quotation ([SIMPLE MONTHLY CALCULATOR](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html#key=my-free-website)) which i cannot understand.

Please help me understand it.